# Difference between SNR and PSNR

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

I understood that SNR is the ratio of signal power to noise power and can be used to measure the effect of noise added to images. Likewise, in PSNR, we take the square of the peak value in the image (in case of an 8 bit image, the peak value is 255) and divide it by the mean square error. Both  SNR and PSNR are used to measure the quality of an image after the reconstruction and higher the value (SNR or PSNR) better is the reconstruction. **What I don't understand is how SNR and PSNR differs in terms of their conclusion about the reconstructed image.
What the PSNR of an image concludes that the SNR of the same image can't conclude?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signal processing (try http://dsp.stackexchange.com).


Comment: In image processing we often use PSNR to measure the quality of reconstructed image

Comment: @PremnathD you should close this question since it's already been answered here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/difference-between-snr-and-psnr

Answer (score 3):

SNR is defined relatieve to signal while PSNR is defined relative to peak dynamic range, i.e. 255 for an 8 bit image. SNR is badly defined for homogeneous images so for reconstruction evaluation often PSNR is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have an image of organ tissues. From the mathematical expression, the only difference between SNR and pSNR is the numerator part: the former selected the region of interest then calculate the mean value of the signal, representing the signal from the organ; while the latter one calculate the maximum value from the organ, and this usually refers to the boundary, since boundary signal is often strong due to the reflection. Both are very useful in quantifying your image contrast, but the pSNR is more useful when you are going to adjust the contrast in the region of interest, for example, there are more features inside the organ rather than boundary, but with a lower signal compared with the boundary signal. Please note that sometimes such adjustment is nonlinear operation, it may maintain the pSNR but increase the SNR.